# ImportError: No module named meep on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, meep

I followed the procedure in [here](https://meep.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Installation/#version-number).

```
sudo apt-get install meep h5utils
```

and tried [this](https://github.com/d-a-v/meep/commit/e92aa4e0f8adde5631f5694529f522bdda0a0069) also.
But still have that error message.

```
xxxx@xxxxxxxxxxxx:~/Downloads$ python3 mie_scattering.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "mie_scattering.py", line 4, in <module>
import meep as mp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'meep'
```

it seems like the python cannot read the meep.
by using the second method mentioned above, it creates several folder under \Downloads.
I can see meep is there.

I ran this also, but still it does not solve the issue.

```
export PYTHONPATH=~/Downloads
```

I checked there are three versions of python in my PC.
Running the `mie_scattering.py` with all version produces the same issue.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the package required to use meep with Python named "mpi4py" ?

`pip install --user mpi4py`

Best regards.